# Ocaml's Graphics.open_graph does not work

Tags: graphics, ocaml

I am trying to follow the [ocaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual039.html) to draw something. But here is a strange response from Ocaml's toplevel. Anyone sees why? Thanks.

```
# #load "graphics.cma";;
# Graphics.open_graph "foo:0";;
_X11TransSocketINETConnect() can't get address for foo:6000: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Exception: Graphics.Graphic_failure "Cannot open display foo:0".
```

Answer (score 5):

I use `Graphics.open_graph " 600x400"`, and it works. Note the space before the resolution specification.

As to why `foo:0` would or would not work, that is not OCaml-specific but something about the X11 server. You probably don't need to, and therefore don't want to, use such specialized feature (opening a window on another display).

Answer (score 1):

[foo](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Foo) term is a common way to specify parts of examples that should be substituted by the user to match local environment.
In your case you probably want to read 3 lines below and open default display :

> Graphics.open_graph ""
>
> > connects to the default display and creates a window with the default geometry.